# Giyeok ㄱ at bottom of syllable pronounced as th

Tags: pronunciation

Someone told me that ㄱ giyeok at the bottom end of syllable is pronounced as th sound. Is this true?

Comment: Who is "someone" and why would you think that? Do you have any examples of where you think this is happening? Have you tried searching for it's pronunciation on google or youtube?

Comment: Unless this individual was speaking of some sort of slang or colloquialism, I have never heard of the described pronunciation of ㄱ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In closed syllables (i.e. if it's the end of the word or a consonant follows it) 받침 (the bottom end of syllable) allows only for 7 sounds:ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅇ.
As you see, ㄱ sound is in the list, so no need to change it to something else.

Any other sounds are converted to one of these seven like follows
ㄲ, ㅋ -> ㄱ
키읔[키윽]
ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅌ -> ㄷ
웃다[욷ː따],  빚다[빋따]
ㅍ -> ㅂ
덮다[덥따]
That's if we are talking about 1-letter 받침. Among cases when 받침 consists of 2 letters there are also none that drastically change ㄱ sound.
I mean, there **is** a rule for opened syllables that if ㄱ at the end of syllable is followed by ㅎ, then the reading changes to an aspirated ㅋ (각하[가카], 밝히다[발키다]), but that's pretty much it.

Plus, there's no sound 'th' in Korean to begin with =)

So no, it's not true that ㄱ at the bottom end of syllable is pronounced as th sound.

For additional info, try googling 표준 발음법, 표준어 규정, 한글 맞춤법.

Source: [표준어 규정 해설](https://www.gyeoremal.or.kr/data/pds/pds_2_2_4.pdf) (Explanation for rules of standard language, chapter 4 Pronunciation of 받침)

Hope I could answer your question!